# How to open an existing Excel file?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am copying a table from Outlook to Excel. The code I have found online copies the table in a new Excel file.

I want to copy the table into an existing Excel file.

Here is the code I am running in Outlook.

```vb
Sub dd()
Dim item As MailItem, x%
Dim r As Object  'As Word.Range
Dim doc As Object 'As Word.Document
Dim xlApp As Object, wkb As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
xlApp.Visible = True

Dim wks As Object
Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)

For Each item In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Set doc = item.GetInspector.WordEditor
    For x = 1 To doc.Tables.Count
        Set r = doc.Tables(x)
        r.Range.Copy
        wks.Paste
        wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Offset(1).Select
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code here

```
Set wkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
```

is what opens the new workbook.  Try replacing this line with something like

```
Set wkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\PathToExcel\File.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help sir. This worked well.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  Please mark this as your answer.