# how to write to an existing excel file

Tags: excel, vb.net

Noob here. I took a coding class in 2011, learned some VB5. Need help with this code. It won't write to `"C:\Users\Dibs\Documents\Sample32.xlsx"`. Neither is it throwing any errors. So nothing to debug.

This code used to open up a new Excel file, but i need to write to an existing one. What am i doing wrong here?

I need the same help as this guy.[Outlook-How to open existing Excel file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607265/how-to-open-an-existing-excel-file)

```
Option Explicit On
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Dim objxlapp As Excel.Application
Dim objxlwrkbk As Excel._Workbook

Dim xlwrkbks As Excel.Workbooks
Dim xlwrkshts As Excel.Sheets
Dim xlwrksht As Excel._Worksheet
Dim range As Excel.range

' Create a new instance of Excel and start a new workbook.
'part of old code
'objxlapp = New Excel.Application()
'objxlwrkbk = xlwrkbks.Add


'this is where my troubles begin
'i cant figure out which variable or object needs the location info of the excel file
'that i want to write the array too
xlwrkbks = objxlapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Dibs\Documents\Sample32.xlsx")
objxlwrkbk = xlwrkbks
xlwrkshts = objxlwrkbk.Worksheets
xlwrksht = xlwrkshts(1)




'Get the range where the starting cell has the address
'm_sStartingCell and its dimensions are m_iNumRows x m_iNumCols.
range = xlwrksht.range("A1", Reflection.Missing.Value)
range = range.Resize(22, 22)

If (Me.FillWithStrings.Checked = False) Then
    'Create an array.
    Dim saRet(22, 22) As Double

    'Fill the array.
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    For iRow = 0 To 22
        For iCol = 0 To 22

            'Put a counter in the cell.
            saRet(iRow, iCol) = iRow * iCol
        Next iCol
    Next iRow

    'Set the range value to the array.
    range.Value = saRet

Else
    'Create an array.
    Dim saRet(22, 22) As String

    'Fill the array.
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    For iRow = 0 To 22
        For iCol = 0 To 22

            'Put the row and column address in the cell.
            saRet(iRow, iCol) = iRow.ToString() + "|" + iCol.ToString()
        Next iCol
    Next iRow

    'Set the range value to the array.
    range.Value = saRet
End If

'Return control of Excel to the user.
objxlapp.Visible = True
objxlapp.UserControl = True

'Clean up a little.
range = Nothing
xlwrksht = Nothing
xlwrkshts = Nothing
xlwrkbks = Nothing

objxlwrkbk.Save()
objxlwrkbk.Close()
objxlapp.Quit()
```

Comment: Take a look at EPPlus (https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) it makes reading/writing xlsx files so much simpler and no need to mess around with all that Excel Application Stuff

Comment: For your current problem you should check the size of you array, Excel row/coloum count start at 1 not 0.

Comment: "Neither is it throwing any errors. So nothing to debug."  - Logic errors tend not to throw compilation nor run-time errors, but they do require debugging.

Comment: i will have a look at EPPULS. @David Sdot Yes ill change them, but that is not the help i need. "xlwrkbks = objxlapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Dibs\Documents\Sample32.xlsx")" My Problem is in this line. I did Leave a comment in my code, where i have troubles at.

Answer (score 0):

`Range` object expects array to have lower bounds as 1 - not zero. Also, the dimensions of receiving range must match with dimensions of array. In order to do that, you need to manually create such array.

Example:

```
Option Infer On

Private Sub TestExcel()

    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application With {.Visible = True}
    Dim xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
    Dim xlSheet = DirectCast(xlBook.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

    '// Create array with custom lower bounds
    '// 5 = number of rows
    '// 2 = number of columns
    '// {1, 1} = lower bounds for rows and columns, respectively
    Dim arr = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Integer), {5, 2}, {1, 1})
    arr.SetValue(1, 1, 1)   '//Assign '1' to first row, first column
    arr.SetValue(50, 1, 2)  '//Assign '50' to first row, second column
    arr.SetValue(2, 2, 1)   '//Assign '2' to second row, first column
    arr.SetValue(100, 2, 2) '//Assign '1' to second row, second column

    '// Transfer array to sheet
    xlSheet.Range("A1:B5").Value = arr

    ' Other stuff - saving, closing etc.

End Sub
```

Comment: Got it this will be helpful later on, i need help with this part of the code.

Comment: (i am writing a financial app), I need help with the first 12 lines of code. The array is filler code. I left a comment in my code, where my problem is. "xlwrkbks = objxlapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Dibs\Documents\Sample32.xlsx")"

Comment: @Dibs xlApp as >>NEW<< ... thats missing in your code

Comment: @David Sdot I'll try that, i did have it in here before, but i removed that line, because i thought it is for starting a brand new excel file and cannot be used to to write to an existing file. But it just starts the Excel app, right?

Comment: @DavidSdot Just like this line does the opposite. objxlapp.Quit()

Comment: objxlapp has the type Excel.Application but its default value is  nothing, thats why you need the to init it with new Excel.Application. Set a breakpoint as the first line and go through your code line by line and check the content of each var, you'll see the problem pretty soon

Comment: @johnyL could you change your code, so it calls a saved excel an reads data from it? That is the part i can not figure out.

Comment: This is what i got right know.
objxlapp = New Excel.Application()
objxlapp.Visible = True
xlwrkbks = objxlapp.Workbooks
xlwrkbks.Open("C:\Users\Dibs\Documents\Sample32.xlsx")
objxlwrkbk = xlwrkbks
xlwrkshts = objxlwrkbk.Worksheets
xlwrksht = xlwrkshts(1)